# Maintain a top-k set in Java

Tags: java

Can't think of a neat way of doing this in java:

I'm streaming sets of strings from a file, line by line.

```
s1 s2 s3
s4 s5
s6 s7 s8 s9 s10
...
```

I load each line into a `TreeSet`, do some analysis and throw it away and move to the next line... I can fit the content of individual lines in memory, but not everything.

Now I want to maintain the top 5 biggest sets of strings I've encountered in the scan so far (storing nothing else).

I'm thinking a `PriorityQueue` with a `SetSizeComparator`, with `add`/`poll` when the queue reaches a size of 5. Anyone got a neater solution?

(I can't brain today. I have the dumb...)

Comment: How are you determining what is the "biggest" set?

Comment: Cardinality of the set... .size()

Comment: Your solution sounds pretty good.  You'll have to `peek()` to know whether the current set is better than the worst of the queue.  You'll also have to break ties in your `compare` function.

Comment: Hmm... also need to randomly select 10 sets (I only know that there's greater than 10 lines)... thinking the same `PriorityQueue` approach with a 'randomised' comparator, but suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a tuple, say LineTuple,  consisting of a line and its string frequency.
2. Have a [min heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) of LineTuples, with comparator as the comparison of the frequency values.
3. For first k lines, insert them into the heap.
4. From (k+1)st line onwards,

   - extract the root, i.e. the tuple with minimum frequency, from the heap, and (This operation is `O( lg k )`).
   - create a tuple with the current line, and insert it into the heap. (This operation is *average* constant time, worst case `O( lg k )`)
5. At any point of time, the `k` tuples contained in the heap are the `k` biggest lines.

I am not fluent in Java, so I can't provide any code sample. But, check [here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/javadoc/com/meapsoft/MinHeap.html), [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/cs245/lecture/MinHeap.java.html).

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much the `PriorityQueue` method I mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't extracting and inserting on every step require reheaping every time around?  So the cost would be O(n * log k).  Where n is the number of items in the stream?  It should be possible to get to O(n + m * log k) where m is the number of items that are greater than the top-k of preceding items (m is proportional to log n in the average case and equal to n in the worst case)?

Comment: Reheaping is included in the `extract root` and `insert` operations.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't the below work?

```
<T> T[] topK(Iterator<? extends T> items, int k, Class<T> clazz, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
  T[] topK = Arrays.newInstance(clazz, k);
  if (k == 0) { return topK; }
  for (int i = 0; i < k && items.hasNext(); ++i) {
    topK[i] = items.hasNext();
  }
  // TODO: what is the appropriate output when there are less than k input?
  Arrays.sort(topK, cmp);
  for (T item; items.hasNext();) {
    item = items.next();
    if (cmp.compareTo(item, topK[k - 1]) < 0) {
      int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(topK, item);
      if (pos < 0) { pos = ~pos; }
      System.arraycopy(topK, pos, topK, pos + 1, k - (pos + 1));
      topK[pos] = item;
    }
  }
  return topK;
}
```

The shifting around is O(k) which is less than ideal, but the number of successful comparisons should decrease as the topK get progressively greater, and the comparison each step is O(log k) which is the same as any heap based approach you would get with PriorityQueues.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I find the `PriorityQueue` more convenient, and will offer roughly the same complexity (slightly better being without the admittedly small cost of the shifting... small cost assuming a relatively small top-k).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm for randomly selecting `k` elements from a stream:

```
from random import randint

def rand_k(a, k):
  ret = []
  n = 0
  for e in a:
    n += 1
    if len(ret) < k:
      ret.append(e)
    else:
      if randint(1, n) <= k:
        ret[randint(0, k-1)] = e
  return ret
```

Note that each element will have probability `k / n` of being selected, where `n` is the total number of elements.  Takes `O(n)` time and `O(k)` memory.

**EDIT**

The probability of choosing the element in position `i` (1-based), with `i > k`, is:

`(k / i) * (1 - (k/(i+1))*(1/k)) * ... * (1 - (k/n)*(1/k))`

That is, the probability of choosing the ith element, and not replacing it by any of the following elements.  Simplifying each factor of the product:

`= (k / i) * (i/(i+1)) * ((i+1)/(i+2)) * ... * ((n-1)/n)`

Which after canceling, results in:

`= k / n`

The case of `i <= k` is similar.

Comment: Nifty. Still haven't fully wrapped my head around the probability guarantee though, but see that the probability of an element remaining progresses as `1 -1/2 -1/3 ... -1/(n-k)`, which I assume gives `k/n`? And that the probability of an insertion gives the same probability of an element remaining up until that point? Not suitable though unless `n>>k`?

Comment: To clarify: This seems to be [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), which performs a _uniform_ selection. If I understand the OP correctly, he is interested in the top-k elements, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TreeSet for this. See the reducer class in this Hadoop example:

https://trac.declarativity.net/browser/hadoop-0.19.2/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/TopK.java?rev=4870#L152

Comment: Yep, it's a *slightly* more expensive form of the heap approach... requires "re-heaping" as per Mike Samuel's comment on another answer. More efficient to check to see if you *should* add it before you insert it.

Comment: @badroit: you're re-heaping a set of k elements, for k a constant, so this will take a trivial amount of time.